# Why does $\int_b^{b+\Delta b}f(x)\;dx=f(b)\Delta b+\mathcal{O}(\Delta b^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

On [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) page it is shown that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(\int_a^bf(x)\;dx\right)=\lim_{\Delta b\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta b}\int_b^{b+\Delta b}f(x)\;dx=\lim_{\Delta b\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta b}\left[f(b)\Delta b+\mathcal{O}(\Delta b^2)\right].$$

I'm interested on why:

$$\int_b^{b+\Delta b}f(x)\;dx=f(b)\Delta b+\mathcal{O}(\Delta b^2)\;\;\;\;?$$

I get why on the right hand side there's the $f(b)\Delta b$, but where does the $\mathcal{O}(\Delta b ^2)$ come from?...why exactly is the term $\mathcal{O}(\Delta b ^2)$  there?

Comment: For me it's like developpement of function for example if |x|<1 then we have $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+^2+x^3 + o(x^3)$ which mean that if x=1/2 then $2=1+1/2+1/4+1/8+o(1/8)$

Comment: The notation "$\mathcal{O}$" depict all of the error you make when you are doing your calculus with a finite precision, it's a very simple explanation and not correct exactly, if you want to know more about this notation [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ;)

Comment: I thank you again x) appreciate  it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image below might help to explain where this term comes from:
[image]

Comment: You are more than welcome my friend :)